# Altitude with geolocation API

Tags: html

I use the geolocation API, there is no problem with latitude and longitude either.
There is with the Altitude. For example, if I get the coordinates for my current location with my mobile phone, GPS integrated, I end up at 115 m instead of 44 m, as with Google maps.
I have the impression that the altitude is always a little more than twice the real size

Does anyone have an explanation for this?
For GeolocationCoordinates.altitudeAccuracy I always only get "undefined", why?

Tom

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

here is some code:

```
function successCallback(position) 
{ 
  document.getElementById("alt").value = position.coords.altitude + ", " + position.coords.altitudeaccuracy; //first false, second "undefined"
  document.getElementById("lat").value = position.coords.latitude;  //right
  document.getElementById("lon").value = position.coords.longitude; //right
  document.getElementById("acc").value = position.coords.accuracy; //apparently correct
}
function errorCallback(error) {if (error.code!=3) alert(error.code.toString()); }
let myGeo = new Object;
myGeo.myNavi = window.navigator.geolocation;
let options = { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 8000, maximumAge: 0 };
myGeo.id = myGeo.myNavi.watchPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, options);
```

I only have handys with android.
My browsers are samsung browser and chrom

Tom

Comment: FYI all details need to go in your question (you need to edit your question), not as an answer (this isn't an actual answer).